Running adb reboot command from python
Running the adb reboot command from code always produces an error. In fact, the device reboots and when adb reboot commend run directly from terminal everything is ok, but I don't know how to handle this correctly in python code (unfortunately all chat GPTt suggestions fail). Probably the connection is lost when rebooting and then error is returned...
Do you have any suggestions or do  you know how to handle it?
Full code:
import subprocess


def execute_adb(adb_command):
    # print(adb_command)
    result = subprocess.run(
        adb_command,
        shell=True,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        text=True,
    )
    if result.returncode == 0:
        return result.stdout.strip()
    print(f"returncode {result.returncode}, stderr: {result.stderr.lower()}, stdout: {result.stdout}")
    return "ERROR"

class AndroidController:
    def __init__(self, device):
        self.device = device

    def is_device_online(self):
        adb_command = f"adb -s {self.device} get-state"
        result = execute_adb(adb_command)
        return result == "device"

    def reset_device(self):
        adb_command = f"adb -s {self.device} shell reboot"
        ret = execute_adb(adb_command)
        return ret

controller = AndroidController("emulator-5554")
print(controller.is_device_online())
controller.reset_device()

Output:
True
returncode 255, stderr: , stdout: 

Process finished with exit code 0


The code shown cannot match the output

It does, maybe in your case output is different from some reasons

It does not. The only way that True could be output is if result == "device" However, you have output a return code of 255 which means the execute_adb() will return "ERROR" and "ERROR" != "device". Furthermore, how can True be output before "returncode 255...". That's a rhetorical question because that cannot happen with the code shown in the question

You are using the wrong command. You execute adb shell reboot but the correct command is adb reboot.

As mentioned by @Robert in the comments the proper way is adb reboot. Both commands will do it but the return code is different, and that's another reason to use this one.
>>> subprocess.run(['adb', 'reboot'])
CompletedProcess(args=['adb', 'reboot'], returncode=0)
>>> subprocess.run(['adb', 'shell', 'reboot'])
CompletedProcess(args=['adb', 'shell', 'reboot'], returncode=255)

